# Why does signal loss increase when the frequency of a signal increases?

Tags: pcb, trace

Particularly in the context of long PCB traces. What is the physical explanation for greater loss at higher frequencies?

Comment: [This is more like what a conductor looks like at extremely high frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3j8P.png). A wire trace becomes infinite impedance at infinite frequency and open gaps become short circuits. A lot changes transitioning from DC to infinite frequency. The world looks different, one end to another.

Answer (score 2):

There's just one reason for energy to be lost in any electrical system, and that's when energy is converted into some form that cannot be recovered by the circuit or conductive path in question. For example, all resistors convert electrical energy into heat, all motors convert it into motion, LEDs convert it into light (electromagnetic radiation) and so on. If this occurs in a conductive path, which is carrying electric current, then that energy is lost to the environment, and can no longer be used in the circuit.

While it isn't really related to frequency, I thought I'd mention resistive losses, for completeness. Since all conductors have some amount of electrical resistance, the very act of passing a current through that conductor is causing energy to be lost as heat, an unrecoverable loss. Consequently, the amount of energy received by whatever was supposed to receive it can never be exactly equal to the energy initially transmitted, and intended for the recipient. There are always unintended resistive paths for current to flow. Resistance of the PCB itself is not infinite, and in some circumstances you may need to design with that in mind. Unintended currents that arise this way are called "leakage current".

A more subtle loss occurs when electrons are accelerated. Electric current is due to a movement en-masse of charges, a "flow". When current changes sharply, (either in direction or speed), those charges are accelerated, and this can result in the emmission of photons of light, like radio waves, microwaves or x-rays. This is what makes radio transmitters and microwave ovens work. Generally, charge acceleration is related to frequency; the higher the frequency, the faster the rate of change of current, and the greater the energy in the photons that are emitted.

Unfortunately this also happens when you don't want it to. You have to be very careful when designing circuits that involve rapidly changing voltages and current, because that translates to rapidly accelerating charges, and electromagnetic radiation. If you don't take great care, you can accidentally build a radio transmitter, with the associated, often significant, energy losses. Even with care, you cannot completely prevent this from happening. If you've ever looked inside any piece of modern digital equipment, you will have seen metal shields and cases all over the place. They are there to absorb that electrmagnetically radiated energy, and keep it from leaving and wreaking havoc on other equipment in the vicinity.

Even harder to understand is the more subtle reasons that current can flow to places that were never intended to receive it. There are two main culprits, inductance and capacitance.

Inductance is due to electrical current creating a magnetic field, and such fields are far reaching. Anything conductive which finds itself inside the magnetic field created by a completely unrelated current flow, will have its own electric current "induced" within it, as the field rises and falls in strength. The thing to understand here is that the effect is more pronounced the faster the field strength changes, which is again related to the frequency of current that is responsible for that field. This results in energy leaving its intended path, and arriving at other locations which may even be completely electrically isolated from it.

The second culprit is capacitance. Capacitors operate due to electric fields, rather than magnetic, but they have one very similar property to inductors; energy is able to transfer to distant, unconnected locations. Importantly, unintended capcitance to ground in combination with resistance of the signal source, path and load, forms a low-pass filter, and this is a major cause of increased attenuation of signal amplitude with frequency.

This transfer of energy due to capacitance and inductance is called "coupling", and when that coupling is undesired or unintended, it is called "parasitic". Every conductor carrying a changing current is inductively coupled to every other conductor, to some degree. Every conductor with a changing voltage is capacitively coupled to every other conductor.

It's worth noting that this coupling works in both directions. Any mutual capacitance or inductance between two conductors is a path by which energy of a signal in *either* conductor can find its way into the other. This is called "cross-talk". Not only do you have attenuation to deal with, but also interference.

A good example of parasitic coupling is the Human body in a room containing high voltage mains wiring at 50 or 60Hz. There is always a parasitic capacitance between the person in the room and the mains wiring, and it can be tens, even hundreds of picofarads. That's enough to get changing currents and voltages in the wiring to produce currents in the person's body, or fluctuate the body's electrical potential. The effects are very small, but they are always there. In this way energy is lost from the mains power supply.

There are few ways to mitigate losses, and signal attenuation. These are some of them:

- Keep intended current path resistances as low as possible, usually by keeping them as short as possible. This helps with inductive, capacitive and radiative losses too.
- Inductive coupling is related mainly to position and orientation of conductive loops with repect to either other. All currents flow in loops, and the larger the loop area, the greater the coupling to other nearby loops. Don't make big loops, or loops within loops. Keep conductive paths as short as possible.
- Capacitive coupling is related to distance between conductors and surface area of conductors. Keep distance between conductors large, when parastic elements are a big concern. Keep signal paths as narrow as is feasible for their expected currents.
- Build signal paths as transmission lines (like coaxial cable) instead of plain conductors. With careful design of the geometry of pairs of conductive paths, it's possible to create paths that do not radiate electromagnetically, or create magnetic or electric fields that extend to neighbouring conductors.
- Waves can be reflected back into a conductor when they reach the end, and there's nothing there to absorb the energy. Reflected waves interfere with incoming waves, and can result in a standing wave, at certain frequencies. If that happens, your conductor becomes a radiating antenna. If there's any chance that the length of a conductor is comparable with the wavelength of light at any frequency component present in the signal, you may mitigate this problem by "terminating" the conductor with an appropriate resistance to ground, to absorb the energy. That is, in itself, a loss of energy, but at least it's a controlled loss.

To summarise, and get to your question, which is about how signals are attenuated, and why it gets worse as frequency increases, the reason is energy loss due to inneficiency caused by one of the above means. Any length of conductor carrying a *changing* current either emits electromagnetic radiation, or has parastic capacitive or inductive coupling to all conductors elsewhere. All three of these effects increase with rate of change of signal current or voltage, which is directly related to signal frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The FR4 material of your PCB is not RF transparent.

It absorbs RF energy and coverts it in heat.

A parameter called epsilon which is a function of frequency f that describes PCB losses.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect, theoretical world, it would not matter.  All frequencies would propagate equally on a given PCB.

Of course we don't live in such a world and all real-world PCB traces have parasitic capacitance, resistance, and inductance.

What makes the difference is that parasitic capacitance and inductance produce frequency dependent effects on a signal.  So the higher the frequency the greater effect that these parasitics have on the signal integrity until you reach such a frequency where the signal disappears into the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the various losses are:

1. DC resistance.
2. AC resistance due to skin effect.
3. Dielectric loss of the substrate.
4. Radiation.
5. Leakage (very small unless your board is contaminated).

There's an article at [Sierra Circuits](https://www.protoexpress.com/blog/losses-in-pcb-transmission-lines/) which goes in to some of the maths regarding PCB transmission line loss.

Answer (score 0):

Actual power loss, where useful signal energy is loss as heat, rather than coupling into other things or reflecting, is ultimately caused by matter, usually electrons, absorbing energy from photons. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(electromagnetic_radiation). Particles of matter will be perturbed by the photons and end up vibrating, rotating and or colliding with each other which produces heat.

This has a frequency dependence for a number of reasons:

1. The Skin effect in conductors
2. The structure and size of materials on a microscopic level relative to the wavelength
3. A shorter wavelength means higher photon energy

In general, it is not always true that loss will increase with signal frequency. Look up the attenuation coefficient of water at different frequencies, it goes up and down several times, but there is a general trend to increase.

Particularly with point 3. which is related to the photoelectric effect, there is a greater chance that electrons will be freed by higher energy photons so higher frequency signals will excite more electrons in a given material and lead to more heat generation.